# How to list a single filetype in google picker

Tags: google-picker

I want to only show files of a certain type (e.g. Spreadsheets).  Is this possible?
I would have thought that specifying `picker.ViewId.SPREADSHEETS` would accomplish this but it appears not.

```js
                const {DocsView, DocsViewMode} = picker
                var view = new DocsView(picker.ViewId.SPREADSHEETS)
                view.setMimeTypes("image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg")
                view.setMode(DocsViewMode.LIST)
                view.setSelectFolderEnabled(false)

                var picker = new picker.PickerBuilder()
                    .enableFeature(picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
                    .setAppId(appId)
                    .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
                    .setDeveloperKey(developerKey)
                    .setCallback(resolve)
                    .addView(view)
                    .build()
                picker.setVisible(true)
```

[image: fi]

Comment: You're setting the types to images (`view.setMimeTypes("image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg")`)

Comment: Thank you! I guess that came along for the ride from the sample code.  Not sure how image types resulted in every other type of file showing up, but it's working once I remove them.